# Adding a trailing 0 to my 0.1, 0.2 values, but not to my 0.25 values

Tags: java, formatting

I have a double value that is pulled in from an external method call. When a 0.6 value comes through, I want it to be changed into 0.60, but I don't wan't to put "0" at the end of my string or else it will make my 0.65 values 0.650.

I had a problem before where it displayed 1.95 as 195000001, but I have fixed this problem.

```
double convPrice = callMethod.totalPriceMethod(); //Calls value from external method and adds to local variable.

totalPrice = Double.toString(convPrice); //local variable is converted to String
totalPrice = String.format("£%.2f", totalPrice ); //Formatting is applied to String
totalPriceLabel.setText(totalPrice); //String is added to JLabel.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use String.format format specifier for floating point numbers:

```
String.format("%.2f", yourNumber)
```

Tutorial at: [Formatting tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html).

Or use a DecimalFormat object.

---

e.g.,

```
  String s = String.format("%.2f", 0.2);
  System.out.println(s);
```

---

Don't convert double to String pre-formatting as that's what the formatting is for. You're doing this

```
double convPrice = callMethod.totalPriceMethod();
totalPrice = Double.toString(convPrice); 
totalPrice = String.format("£%.2f", totalPrice ); 
totalPriceLabel.setText(totalPrice);
```

When you want to do something like this:

```
double convPrice = callMethod.totalPriceMethod();
// totalPrice = Double.toString(convPrice);  // ???????
totalPrice = String.format("£%.2f", convPrice); 
totalPriceLabel.setText(totalPrice);
```

Since you're converting to currency, perhaps even better is to use a NumberFormat currencyInstance.

e.g.,

```
  NumberFormat currencyInstance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
  double convPrice = callMethod.totalPriceMethod();
  totalPriceLabel.setText(currencyInstance.format(convPrice));
```

Comment: Hi, when I implement this code, it returns: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String

Comment: @MatthewLevene: then you're using it wrong. Show how you're trying to use it.

Comment: Hi there, just tried again and your method works, thanks! The problem is occuring when I'm trying to get the value through  a method, but if I hardcode the '0.2' in, it converts to 0.20.

Comment: @MatthewLevene `java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String` is telling you that you're trying to pass the format method a string instead of a float. Check the return type of your method. **Edit:** read your code, your making your double a string by calling `Double.toString(Double)`. This is why it is being passed a string.

Comment: @dohaqatar7 in order to meet the criteria of the JLabel's .setText() method, it requires a String. Is there any way I can allow double variables to be entered? -- If I can enter a double value, then I don't need to convert. :)

Comment: @MatthewLevene `String.format()` returns a `String`, so as long as your passing the double through the format method, you should end up with a string being passed to `setText()`.

Comment: @MatthewLevene: that depends on what you mean by `"enter a double value"`. How are the users entering values? If you're using a JSpinner or a JFormattedTextField, then yes you can get a numeric value. If a JTextField, then you'll get a String which can be converted to double.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The user enters input via JTextField, which then fires off to another class, gets the double value, and returns it and attempts to display it in the way I've tried. -- They enter a String something like "Bread"

Comment: @MatthewLevene: then if still stuck, show the pertinent code and describe the details of your current problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've updated my problem with explained stages if you'd like to take a look. :)

Comment: @MatthewLevene: see latest edit regarding currency instance. I'd make the currencyInstance NumberFormat variable a field.